# Quantum mechanics and spin $1/2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, representation-theory

I was reading a book but, I am getting confused in a part which claims that:

$$\exp\left(\frac{-i \vec S \cdot \hat n \, \phi}{\hbar}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{-i \vec \sigma \cdot \hat n \, \phi}{2}\right)$$

where
$\vec S=(S_x,S_y,S_z)$
and
$\vec\sigma = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3)$ (Pauli).

As the book doesn't show a proof, I think this should be immediate to me. Yet, I can not see why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a convention. The operators given by $\hat S$ are written in terms of the Pauli matrices such that

$$\hat S = \frac{\hbar}{2} \hat \sigma$$

Answer (score 3):

For spin 1/2, one possible representation uses the Pauli matrices with
$$S_i = \dfrac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_i. $$
There is a subsection discussing this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)).

Notice that this will not always be true. There are other representations of the spin, and, in those representations, the spin will be given by different matrices.